# For every positive integer $a$, find a composite number $n$ such that $n|a^n-a$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, integers

Hi guys I got this question in the Algebra section of my Math Test and I am not sure how to solve it.

Any help would be regarded.

**The question is written more clearly below**

For every positive integer $a$, find a composite number $n$ such that $n|a^n-a$.

Comment: Hint:  Try factoring.  Handle the case $a=1$ separately

Comment: @Asher2211 1 is not composite (or prime), it's the only positive natural number that is neither

Comment: Refer [Carmichael number](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number)

Comment: @Alan I missed the condition that n is composite.

Comment: For a composite: $a|a(a^{a-1}-1)$ (so set $n=a$ when $a$ is composite). Any composite number will suffice for $a=1$. Then you need to handle when $a$ is prime.

Comment: @Mark thank you for giving me a hint. Unfortunately, I am not getting it to do further. If possible and if you have time, can you please add an answer to my question with complete and detailed solution?

Comment: @user2661923 OK that's fine, I respect the policy. But atleast guide me properly in the right direction step by step that what should I do first and then what should be the further process? Don't just give examples without any proper guidelines.

Comment: @KhubaibKhawar Here's a general hint:  Read the policies of a site you go to looking for help,  then don't complain when people follow them.  We generally give NOTHING on what are called "Problem Statement Questions", aka questions that just state a problem with no thoughts/work/anything from you.   I bent enough to give you a starting hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is from "Elementary Number Theory" by Sierpinski:

$n|a^n-a$

If a is composite we may set $n=a$ then $n|a^n-a$. If $a=1$ we may take for example $n=4$ because $1^4-1$ is divisible by 4. When $a$ is a prime greater than 2 we can take $n=2a$ because in this case $a$ is odd and even number $a^{2n}-a$ is divisible by $n$ and 2 and consequently by $2a=n$.

It remains only the case where $a=2$. In this case we may let $n=341=11\times 31$, which gives $341|2^{341}-2$ because:

$2^{10}-1\equiv 0\bmod 11$

$\Rightarrow 2^{340}-1\equiv 0\bmod 11$

which means $2^{341}-2\equiv 0\bmod 11$

also:

$2^5-1\equiv 2^{340}-1\equiv 0\bmod 31$

therefore :

$11\times 31=341|2^{341}-2$

Remarks:

1- M. Chipola proved that for any natural number n, there exist infinitely many composite numbers like n such that $a|a^{n-1}-1$

2- A. Schnitzel proved that for any integer like a and natural number  like m there exist two numbers $p>m$ and $q>m$ such that $a^{pq}-a$ is divisible by $pq$.

It is not known that there exist infinitely many composite number like n such that $n|a^n-a$. Another number of this type is $n=561=3\times 11\times 17$.

It can be proved that for any natural number like a there exist finite even number like n such that $n|a^n-a$

We  can construct such numbers n and a using above method.